# Shouldn't tags "antonym" and "антоним" be created?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I've been editing a new question on the main site related to antonyms and I wondered why there was no corresponding tag. Although there was one for synonims. I don't have enough reputation to create it myslef. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Done. By the way, to create tags one needs 150 points of reputation, and to suggest tag synonyms — 1250.

---

[Сделано](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC). Кстати, для создания ярлыков нужна [репутация](https://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges) 150. А чтобы связать «антоним» и «antonym», нужна репутация 1250 + 5 голосов по вопросам или ответам с этим ярлыком.